# Invoke-command path null?

Tags: powershell

I am working on this command to be able to view and edit a registry key remotely to a computer on a joined domain when I need to test something. In this case, I am looking at Excel's "vbawarninsg" key. This works just fine.

```
cls
$computername = Read-Host "Enter computer name..."
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername {Get-ItemProperty -Path 'REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\xxxxxxx\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\excel\security' } | 
Select-Object PSComputerName, vbawarnings, PSParentPath | fl
$name = "vbawarnings"
```

The next part is to set a new value for the "vbawarnings" key using New-ItemProperty. When I assigned a variable for the -Path name it gives me an error "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null."

This is the script that gives me an error

```
cls
$computername = Read-Host "Enter computer name..."
$registryPath = 'REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\xxxxxxx\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\excel\security'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername {Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath } | 
Select-Object PSComputerName, vbawarnings, PSParentPath | fl
$name = "vbawarnings"

$value = Read-Host "To modify...Enter a value"
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value `
-PropertyType DWORD -Force -Verbose | Out-Null
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks all for the input. After playing with this for hours, the command below worked for me. Seem simple and at the time I couldn't think straight and now I fully understand how it works.

cls
$cn = "my remote machine"
$value = Read-Host "Enter a value"
Invoke-Command -cn $cn {
    New-ItemProperty -Name vbawarnings -Value $value ` -PropertyType DWORD -Path "REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\xxxxxxx\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\excel\security" -Force -Verbose
}

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a variable remotely (such as the case with `Invoke-Command`), you need to use the `$using:` variable scope:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn {
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $using:regPath
}
```

or pass it as a parameter:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn {
    param($path)

    Get-ItemProperty -Path $path
} -ArgumentList '-path', $regPath
```

---

## [See this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: I'm not sure why it is saying "cannot find path xxxx it doesn't exist". Maybe I'm typing it wrong?

Comment: have you checked the HKU hive is loaded when you enter a remoting session? @DudebePSing

Comment: Yeah I can see all the hives no problem..not sure what else to try.

Comment: @DudebePSing Consider using `Enter-PSSession` and ensuring that the drive is accessible and the path exists.

Comment: Do you know why when I used the command I pasted above under my comment, that I can change the value to 0 when it was from 2 (GP default). But then changing it from 0 to 1,2,3,4 won't let me? I did not see any error message or anything. Verbose displays that the value stayed at 0. Nothing was change. It's weird..

Comment: @DudebePSing I'd suggest using `Set-ItemProperty`.  Consider adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to your commands to trigger a terminating error.  From there, you could observe the `$Error` automatic variable for details (this is an array with 0 being the newest error).  It also enables you to effectively use `try/catch`.

Answer (score -1):

When you do Invoke-Command, that scriptblock gets sent to the remote server.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername {Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath }
```

On the remote server, $registryPath is null even though you have it locally in your script.

So just hardcode the registry path instead:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername {Get-ItemProperty -Path 'REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\xxxxxxx\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\excel\security' }
```

Comment: yeah you're right. I interpreted the question as "why is $registryPath null?"  I didn't know about the $using scope before, otherwise I would have mentioned it.