# How to run Parallel For Each Loop on PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script below that runs a scheduled task on multiple remote servers:

```
Workflow Invoke-ParallelWorkflow
{
    $ListFile='server_list.txt'
    $ServerList = (get-content $ListFile) -match '^[^#\r\n].*'

    ForEach ($Server in $ServerList)
    {
        InlineScript{ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock { schtasks /run  /tn MM\fileOSclean }}
    }
}

Invoke-ParallelWorkflow

pause
```

The problem is it isn't reading the value of the $Server variable

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At Invoke-ParallelWorkflow:15 char:15
+
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

The script works if I remove the ForEach and hard code each of the server name like so:

```
Workflow Invoke-ParallelWorkflow
{
    parallel
    {
        InlineScript{ Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName1 -ScriptBlock { schtasks /run  /tn myScheduleTask }}
        InlineScript{ Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName2 -ScriptBlock { schtasks /run  /tn myScheduleTask }}
        InlineScript{ Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName3 -ScriptBlock { schtasks /run  /tn myScheduleTask }}
    }
}

Invoke-ParallelWorkflow

pause
```

The server_list.txt has a valid content and I can output it when running `write-host $Server` inside the ForEach command

Comment: If I had to guess, `InlineScript` is starting a new environment, but I'd have to check the doc.  [See: the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_inlinescript?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228537/invoke-command-path-null